# do i need to build a vm to use a vpn

Tags: vpn, virtualization, cloud, google

I want to connect to a custom VPN in google cloud platform, and even potentially route that vpn traffic to a different vpn in a separate region using google cloud services. However, I'm assuming I need to route this traffic through multiple VM instances, thus causing me to purchase more cloud space and build multiple VM instances. Is there a way to use cloud services to access a small partition of their services to build a console that is dedicated to routing my traffic to a VPN in the cloud? I want to build a VPN in a way other than building a VM in the cloud and then creating and connecting a VPN through that VM. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Given [GCP has a cloud VPN product](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview), no you don't need to run your own to get onto their network.